# Trying to calculate the average in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to write some code which takes in any number of entries and stores it in an `ArrayList` given a specific condition. What I'm not able to do is find the average of the values stored in the `ArrayList`. Here's the code written so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    private ArrayList<Integer> temp;
    private int t;
    private int count = 0;

    public void main() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        temp = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Enter temperatures: ");
        do {
            t = input.nextInt();
            if (t == -99) {
                System.out.println("Program Terminating..");
                break;
            } else {
                temp.add(t);
            }
        } while (t != -99);
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
            if (temp.get(i) > 40) {
                count++;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

Comment: With Java 8 you can simply `list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum() / list.size()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't seem to understand this. Could you explain it in a different way? Much appreciated.

Comment: OK. So, how would you compute an average, with a pen and a paper. Or with just your brain? Is an average a count? If not, why do you count items? Assume the list contains 2, 4, 5, 6 and 8.

Comment: I want to print out the number of temperatures that are above 40, hence used count. Finding the average is another function that I'm trying to add to the program.

Comment: @MarounMaroun or better: `list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).average().getAsDouble()`

Comment: @JBNizet that's indeed better :)

Comment: Thanks a lot of the input guys. Added it works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a funky condition there; you're only doing operations if the value is greater than 40.  The code below takes those into account; if you don't desire that, then remove the conditional.

In a traditional manner, you can use an enhanced-for with a counter to get all of the values greater than 40 and average those...

```
double sum = 0;
for(Integer i : temp) {
    if(i > 40) {
        sum += i;
        count++;
    }
}

if(count != 0) { // avoid divide-by-zero error here
    System.out.println(sum / count);
}
```

...or with Java 8, you can use streams, filter out those that are less than 40, and get the average as a double instead:

```
System.out.println(temp.stream()
                       .filter(x -> x > 40)
                       .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                       .average()
                       .getAsDouble());
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for this solution. The condition that I'm trying to implement in this code is A) I need the count of temperatures over 40 and B) I need the average of all the temperatures entered including the ones below 40.

Comment: The code shouldn't be hard to extend to suit that need; this is more or less an example.  I leave the rest as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
 long total =0;
  for(int i=0;i < temp.size(); i++){
    if(temp.get(i) > 40){
        count++;
        total+=temp.get(i);
    }
   }

    double mean=0;
   if(count!=0)
        mean = total/count;
```

Comment: That will return 1 for the average of 1, 2, 2.

Comment: Since `total` is a long, `count` will be promoted to a long as well, and your result will be equivalent to integer division; that is, the decimal part is truncated.